# restrict qualifier compilation error

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 10.05, and mingw. It seems the compiler does not recognized restrict qualifier and return "error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'src'". Do I need to pass any compiler option in order to compile it correctly?

```
int inet_pton4 (const char *restrict src, unsigned char *restrict dst)
```

p/s: it seems mingw does not support inet_pton4, so i tried to integrate an open-source version into my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your compiler does not support the `restrict` keyword, just take that keyword out <sup>(a)</sup>.

It's used to indicate to the compiler that you (the developer) promise that the pointers follow certain properties involving aliasing, and this, in turn, allows the compiler to perform certain optimisations that would otherwise not necessarily be safe.

If you leave off that keyword in a compiler that supports it, it prevents those optimisations (slight downside).

If you leave it off for compilers that *don't* support that keyword, the downside is nil (since they don't support those optimisations anyway) and the upside is considerable, as in "it will compile for you" :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You may want to ensure you're compiling in C99 mode first. While it *may* be true that you're using an older `gcc` that doesn't understand `restrict`, it's equally possible that you're not compiling in C99 mode, such as with `-std=c99` (`gcc` docs seem to indicate that `restrict` has been supported even back to version 3.0).

If, for some reason you cannot activate C99 mode, I think `gcc` has an extension that allows you to use `__restrict`.

Comment: Easy way to take the keyword out (if necessary): use `-Drestrict` on the command line.  The preprocessor will take it out for you, and you don't have to edit any code.  Makes it easy to put back in the future if you move to a C99 compiler, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since `restrict` is new in C99, and since, as @paxdiablo points out, omitting the `restrict` keyword doesn't really hurt anything, you can do this:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
#define restrict /* nothing */
#endif
```

Put this in a header that's `#include`d by everything in your project (or at least by everything that uses `restrict`).

This should let your code compile with any C compiler, whether it supports C99 or not.  It should even work for a compiler that doesn't define `__STDC_VERSION__`.

**But**, since you're using MinGW, which uses gcc, using `gcc --std=c99` should also solve the problem (as @paxdiablo also points out).

You can safely do both.  (And the `#if` solution is likely to be useful to others.)